# Git: Is there any GUI for setup a central repository?

Tags: git, graphical-user-interface

I am looking for a wizard-GUI-like interface to create a central repository Git accessible to multiple users with authentication.

Is there any GUI for an easy setup a central repository on windows or linux? Maybe a gitosis graphical user interface frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at hosted git hub. There is not a ready GUI that I am aware of for seting it up.

Comment: Sincere answer. GitHub seems to be nice but I want to setup the server and keep the data for me.

Answer (score 2):

Github has also launched [Enterprise Github](https://enterprise.github.com/), a local installable version of Github. Might be exactly what you are looking for, if you have a budget available.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect such an GUI should do?

[Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) has a nice and easy installer, but it is not "windowed".

Comment: A GUI should make the tedious task for me so that I don't have to memorize each keyword or basic steps. It's like using Eclipse instead of nano program for java programming. Eclipse provides you autocompletion. So that you can concentrate at a higher level instead of thinking about every detail of the Java syntax or library calls. A well done GUI should make you faster because you trust it and you do not have to worry about details. I like command line when I script. Not more.